# Email notification from channel form

Tags: safecracker, notification

I need to send an email notification to an specific address after channel form is submited.. The email address depend on the selection of a field in the form..  I know there's might be a hook for that but i don't know how to use it..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many trial and error (as i'm not a real programmer).. i finally found something that works.. 
For all the newbies like me.. you need to have an addon.setup.php file and a ext.YOUR-THING.php as explain in the main doc
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/addon_setup_php_file.html and https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extensions.html..
Then my main script inside my extension file..

```
function channel_form_submit_entry_end( $cf ) {

    ee()->load->library( 'email' );

    $var = ee()->input->post( 'YOUR-POST-INPUT-NAME', TRUE );
    if ( $var == '123' ) {
        $recipient = 'email1@xyz.com';
    } else {
        $recipient = 'emai2@xyz.com';
    };


    ee()->load->library( 'email' );
    ee()->load->helper( 'text' );

    ee()->email->wordwrap = true;
    ee()->email->mailtype = 'text';
    ee()->email->from( 'email@xys.com' );
    ee()->email->to( $recipient );
    ee()->email->subject( 'YOUR SUBJECT' );
    ee()->email->message( entities_to_ascii( 'YOUR BODY MESSAGE' ) );
    ee()->email->Send();

}
```

I know it may not be the cleanest script by it works!.. 
If someone wish to clean this.. please feel free!

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook. Find details here:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension-hooks/module/channel-form.html#channel_form_submit_entry_endchannel_form_obj

All you have to do this is to create an extension file. Initialize email library. You can find fields data in 'parameter you passed in function' or in POST.